# Reason for automatic creation of RectTransform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating 2 GameObjects.

One automatically gets a RectTransform without explicitely adding one, the other doesn't.

In this case, a RectTransform isn't added, but it can be accessed:

```
    GameObject nCanvasGO = new GameObject("CanvasContainer");
    Canvas nCanvas = nCanvasGO.AddComponent<Canvas>();
    nCanvas.renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;
    nCanvasGO.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
    nCanvasGO.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();

    RectTransform rtCanvasGO = nCanvasGO.GetComponent<RectTransform>(); //can be accessed, isn't null
```

This one does not have a RectTransform:

```
    GameObject nAnimInfo = new GameObject("AnimInfo");
    RectTransform rtAnimInfo = nAnimInfo.GetComponent<RectTransform>(); // is null
```

I would therefore like to ask if adding a Canvas component to a GameObject add a RectTransform or what else might be the reason here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Adding a canvas to a Gameobject will automatically change the `Transform` to a `RectTransform`. This is because the rect transform is the 2D equivalent of `Transform`, with some additional functionality like anchoring.

From the Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RectTransform.html):

> The Rect Transform component is the 2D layout counterpart of the Transform component. Where Transform represents a single point, Rect Transform represent a rectangle that a UI
>    element can be placed inside. If the parent of a Rect Transform is also a Rect Transform, the child Rect Transform can also specify how it should be positioned and sized relative to the parent rectangle.

<sub>The docs don't actually clearly state anywhere that a transform gets replaced by RectTransform automatically though...</sub>

Furthermore Canvas depends on RectTransform, and can thus not be used without having a RectTransform. You can see ths when you try to delete the rect transform from a canvas. It will pop up saying "Can't remove RectTransform because Canvas depends on it".

Any other UI component you add to a GameObject will also automatically add the Recttransform component (I.E image, text etc.). this has the same reason as Canvas, that they depend on RectTRansform.

You will also notice that any GameObject you make that is a child of a canvas will also have a RectTransform by default, so that it can anchor itself relative to the parents (canvas in this example) rect transform. You can delete the rectTransform from these Objects as long as none of its components depend on RectTransform. Though i don't see why this would be desired, as any child of a canvas should be some form of UI like an image or text. And should thus require the RectTransform.